# I am trying to create a function for sudoku to check to see if a a number from 1-9 does not repeat

Tags: c, function

> [image: link]

I am writing for a function for a program and I am having trouble keeping track if I am writing this function correctly also implementing the band checking component to make sure the numbers inside also don't repeat.

I have tried to make 2 for loops to go through my array to make sure my rows at least are checked but would I have to do another 2 for loops to check my rows? Most importantly how do I implement "value" I am so confused.

my code should check to see if 
Each cell holds a number between 1–9 (for the filled cells) or 0 (for the blanks).
• No number is repeated in any row.
• No number is repeated in any column.
• No number is repeated in any box.
I don't want to over complicate this project as I am a complete beginner so if there is a faster method to achieving this please let me know.
`

```
int
is_valid_board(int board[9][9])
{   int n1=0,n2=0,n3=0,n4=0,n5=0,n6=0,n7=0,n8=0,n9=0,n0=0;
    int true;
    int i,j;
    int value;

    for( i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            while (board[i][j] > 9 || board[i][j] < 0) {
                if (board[j][i] == 0) {
                    n0++;
                } else if (board[i][j] == 1) {
                    n1++;
                } else if (board[i][j] == 2) {
                    n2++;
                } else if (board[i][j] == 3) {
                    n3++;
                } else if (board[i][j] == 4) {
                    n4++;
                } else if (board[i][j] == 5) {
                    n5++;
                } else if (board[i][j] == 6) {
                    n6++;
                } else if (board[i][j] == 7) {
                    n7++;
                } else if (board[i][j] == 8) {
                n8++;
            } else if (board[i][j] == 9) {
                n9++;
            } else
                return 1;

           }
       }
        if(n0 != 1)
            return 0;
        if(n1 != 1)
            return 0;
        if(n2 != 1)
            return 0;
        if(n3 != 1)
            return 0;
        if(n4 != 1)
            return 0;
        if(n5 != 1)
            return 0;
        if(n6 != 1)
            return 0;
        if(n7 != 1)
            return 0;
        if(n8 != 1)
            return 0;
        if(n9 != 1)
            return 0;
        }

    }
 `
```

Comment: The function should return 0 if the board parameter violates any of the Sudoku rules and 1 if the
board is valid. You have to check four constraints:

Comment: you will get better/more answers if you tag the language you're working in

Comment: It seems to me that a "_faster method_" method is not what you want.  Certainly a _simpler_ method.  Start by using an array n[9] rather than separate n1, n2 etc.  That will allow iteration over results rather than copy&pasted repetition.

Comment: The assignment requires you to use a "bit set array", which you have not done.  Since that is not specifically a _thing_ in C, presumably it is something you have been taught in class?

Comment: I've modified the code a bit changing the array also this is further detail regarding the first function I have to write about  https://imgur.com/a/VKufidx

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what is your question, but I'll base my answer on your assignment. Also, I didnt understnad what you're trying to do there. It's the best if you would explain the logic of your function, what its get as input and what is the output.

I guess that `int n0-9`  are vairables that counts how many time each digits appear - for that you asked to use bit set/clear. 
for that run over the matrix with double for loops and then for each cell you cross, check if his corresponding row/col contain this value.

I wrote something which might help you. I didnt run it to check the output, but for start try to use it.
I used bit set as you were asked for.

first example:

```
int
is_valid_board(int board[9][9])
int i,j;
int value;
int value_bit; //convert row/col value into bit set
int bit_arr_rows[10] = {0}, bit_arr_cols[10] = {0}; //bit array for rows and cols
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        value = board[i][j];

        //check for valid values
        if(value < 0 || value > 9)
            return 0; 

        //check if the value appear in rows bit array
        value_bit = 1 << i;
        if(bit_arr_rows[value] & value_bit)
            return 0;

        //set the value's bit in the rows bit array.
        bit_arr_rows[value] |= value_bit;

        //check if the value appear in cols bit array
        value_bit = 1 << j;
        if(bit_arr_cols[value] & value_bit)
            return 0;

        //set the value's bit in the cols bit array.
        bit_arr_cols[value] |= value_bit;

    }
}
return 1; //board is valid
```

The logic: I initialized 2 bit arrays, 1 for cols and 1 for rows.
Each bit array have 10 slots for each value in range of 0-9.
Everytime I run over new value on row 'i' and column 'j', I check if the i'th bit is set on rows bit array and the same on column bit array for j'th bit. if it doesnt appear I set the j'th/i'th bit on the col/row bit array.

second example (I dont think its exactly what you've been asked for, but it suppose to work):

```
int
is_valid_board(int board[9][9])
int i,j,k;
int value;
int check_if_appear; //array of bits that contain the number we want to check if appear.
int number;         // array of bits that contain the number we cross for each number we check.
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        value = board[i][j];

        //check for valid values
        if(value < 0 || value > 9)
            return 0; 

        //set the value's bit in the bit array.
        check_if_appear = 1; 
        check_if_appear <<= value;

        for(k=0;k<10;k++)
        {
            //check if value appear on corresponding cols
            number = 1 << board[i][k];
            if( number & check_if_appear)
                return 0;

            //check if value appear on corresponding rows
            number = 1 << board[k][j];
            if( number & check_if_appear)
                return 0;
        }           
    }

return 1; //board is valid
```

the logic:
Assume you get a board (matrix 9x9), run over the board and for each cell
set bit array corresponding to the value of the cell value. for example assume on `board[2][3] == 5`
so set check_if_appear = 3 (2^5 or b0000000000100000 in binary).
then run over the 2nd row and check if any value is already exists. return this procedure for the 3rd cols.